# Verify loop_rate

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have set a loop rate in the following way:

```
ros::Rate r(100)
while(ros::Ok()){
    ros::SpinOnce();
    function();
    r.sleep();
}
```

Is there anyway to verify if I am accomplish this rate or if the function is taking longer than that?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205754/verify-loop_rate/) by [Carollour](https://answers.ros.org/users/21953/carollour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
If you publish a topic you can verify the loop rate with:

```
rostopic hz /your_topic_name
```

---

Originally posted by [Chaos](https://answers.ros.org/users/15091/chaos/) with karma: 396 on 2015-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carollour](https://answers.ros.org/users/21953/carollour/) on 2015-03-24**:
thank you, that was it.